# Automatic pay-ins and payout on React/Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, payment-gateway

How can I create a website using React/Next.js where users can create a circle and contribute money weekly, fortnightly or monthly and the total sum is paid to a member of the group and the contribution continues until all members of the circle receive a payout. e.g. The traditional ajo, esusu, or pardna scheme.

I want a situation where the contributions are collected from each member bank account weekly or monthly automatically with secure payment gateway at a scheduled date and send the payout to the collector’s bank account automatically.

How can I achieve this using React/Next.js and which secure payment gateway can handle automatic bank debit (pay-ins) and payout in Australia.

I want to use PayPal but don't know how? I will be grateful if someone should point me in the right direction as to this project. What other alternative payment gateway can handle direct bank debit, payout and transaction status update.